# Problems deploying SailsJs to Heroku

Tags: heroku, sails.js, sails-mongo

I am in the process of deploying a basic SailsJS application to Heroku. I have done this a few times before without any hiccups; which leads me to believe this might be a documentation or deprecation issue.

When I deploy the application, this is the error that I am getting over and over:

```
Must contain an `adapter` key referencing the adapter to use.
In model (class), invalid connection :: mongoProd
```

I am currently using the following versions:

```
sails: 0.11.4
sails-mongo: 0.11.6
```

Now, I can confirm that have the `sails-mongo` adapter installed (duh). As far as my production.js is concerned, this is what I have:

```
environment: 'production',
  hookTimeout: 30000, // 30 seconds

  // blueprint settings
  blueprints: {
    rest: false,
    shortcuts: false
  },

  session: {
    adapter: 'redis',
    host: //,
    port: 9592,
    user: //,
    pass: //,
  },
  models: {
    connection: 'mongoProd',
    migrate: 'alter'
  },
  port: process.env.PORT || 5000,

  log: {
    level: "silent"
  }
```

And finally, this is what my connections.js looks like:

```
mongoProd: {
    adapter: 'sails-mongo',
    url: process.env.MONGOLAB_URI
  },
```

Why am I continuing to get this redundant error even though I clearly have everything defined?

Comment: Could you paste the code in which you use the configuration from `production.js`?

Comment: This is all of the configuration that I have. Based on what [the documentation says](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/configuration) I was under the impression that whatever you define in the `production.js` overrides any configurations that are set within the `config` directory; in this case my connections configurations.

Comment: Do you have `process.env.MONGOLAB_URI` defined. Check using Heroku CLI command `heroku config:get MONGOLAB_URI`